# Is "being dead" important to solve Zork I

Tags: zork

In Zork I, after a certain point (which I have no idea what is, discovering the altar perhaps), if you die, you are transported to the *Entrance to Hades*, and you are in a dead state. E.g. typing `diagnose` will confirm that you are dead.

In the dead state, there is very little you can do, e.g. you cannot hold or pick up items, as your hand passes through the items. The only thing I have found out so far that I can do in this state is to move to the Altar and pray, in which case I get revived.

Subsequently dying seems to end the game.

Is there an important puzzle that can only be solved in the dead state?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Nope, you can get all the treasure and win Zork without ever dying.  Being in this state is just the game being a bit forgiving and giving you a second chance.

You can confirm this by [checking a walkthrough,](http://www.gamefaqs.com/pc/564446-zork-i/faqs/20848) or by digging around in the [full source to the game.](http://gunkies.org/wiki/Zork#Source_code)